# Displaying a link in microposts and comments that links to the author's profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a Micropost model that have the following attributes:

```
<Micropost id: 1, content: "test", user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-25 15:34:30", updated_at: "2012-01-29 11:07:53", title: "asdasdad">
```

an User model with the following attributes:

```
<User id: 1, email: "alex@gmail.com", username: nil, etc...>
```

and a Comment model with the following attributes:

```
<Comment id: 1, content: "sdf", micropost_id: 1, user_id: nil, created_at: "2012-01-29 11:10:42", updated_at: "2012-01-29 11:10:42">
```

So far, I've only accomplished this:

- Display the **username** of the author of a micropost
- Display the **ID** of the authors of the microposts' comments

  ```
  <h2>Micropost Index</h2>
  <% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>

  <%= micropost.title %></td>
  <%= micropost.content %></td>
  <%= link_to 'Show', micropost %></td>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_micropost_path(micropost) %></td>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', micropost, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
  ```

  ```
  <h2>Comments</h2>

  <% @micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p>
      <b>Comment:</b>
      <%= comment.content %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>Commenter</b>
      <%= comment.user_id %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  ```
- I don't know how to create a link to the authors profile (e.g. mysite.com/users/1).
- I don't how to retrieve the name of the author of a comment and the link to his/her profile

**EDIT:**

Models:

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username

  has_many :microposts
  has_many :comments

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
      user
    else # Create a user with a stub password. 
      User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
    end
  end
end
```

**micropost.rb:**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end
```

**comment.rb:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  belongs_to :micropost
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Micropost controller:

**controllers/microposts.rb**

```
  def show
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @micropost = Micropost.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @micropost = @user.microposts.new(params[:micropost])
    @micropost.save
    redirect_to @micropost
  end
```

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a link to the user you can use

```
<%= link_to comment.user.username, comment.user %>
```

In general part of the "Rails Magic" is, that you if you set up an association correctly, that you can access the related objects through the dot notation. That means, you don't need to say `comment.user_id` but instead go directly for the associated user object, e.g. `comment.user.username` or `comment.user.email` ... you get the idea :)

In order to to this you should have set up your models like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :username #username should obviously not allow nil values
  has_many :microposts
  has_many :comments
end

class MicroPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please check my **EDIT** I included my models. But for some reason I'm getting this: `undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Strange but only `comment.user` works (displays: `#<User:0xa5cc998>`). Is it because I need to set foreign keys in the comments table (e.g. user_username)?

Comment: It is probably because you haven't set the user_id in your `MicroPost` instance. Check your `@micropost` to see wether user_id is empty or not. If empty, check your controller to confirm that you use something like `@user.microposts.create(…)`or similar.

Comment: @timbrandes Sorry I'm not very sure what do you mean by that. Please check my EDIT I added part of my micropost controller (apparently, I do have something like: `@user.microposts.new`).

Comment: you get the error because your username is nil in your example code: <User id: 1, email: "alex@gmail.com", username: nil, etc...> - if you just use comment.user, you get the ruby object..

Comment: thats why i recommended using validation on the username

Comment: @timbrandes Strange this works: `@micropost.user.username` but this don't: `comment.user.username` (I added the `validates_presence_of :username` and added usernames too all users but still getting the same error).

Comment: then probably the comment does not have a (valid) user_id

Comment: @frank blizzard Hey you were right I thought when `comment.user.username` was nil, Rails just ignored it and displayed nothing. I didn't know it just stopped the whole application. Thanks a lot!

Comment: there are different handlings depending on the environment. in development usually you want to get noticed when calling a nil value. you can find it under config/environments/... (config.whiny_nils = true)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Link:
=link_to "User profile", user_path(comment.user)

# Name of the author
=comment.user.username
```

or since you have user_id in both `Micropost` and `Comment`

```
# Link:
=link_to "User profile", (@micropost.user)

# Name of the author
=@micropost.user.username
```

Comment: for some reason `comment.user.username` throws the error: `undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass`